# bash : Matching a name with a template list in Unix

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to match a file name with a list of templates stored in a variable .

My variable holding the templates to match is like below

```
TEMPLATE_LIST="Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???"
```

And my variable holding the file name is FILE_NAME.

If FILE_NAME="Sample.csv" or FILE_NAME="TEST_12.csv" like that command should return success . And if the FILE_NAME is like "TEST_123.csv" it should return Failure as it is not matching any template stored in the variable .

I was able to parse through the list and check file_name with one by one template  in a loop , But that is a lengthy process .

How can we achieve this in a single command ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `echo` the `TEMPLATE_LIST` variable without quotes and let it be expanded by shell:

```
echo $TEMPLATE_LIST
```

Comment: Am not sure I understand this answer! Could you please explain a bit more on this? It is throwing error for me.

Comment: What error are you getting? I tested this before posting. By not using quotes around `TEMPLATE_LIST` we let shell expand the glob patterns stored in the value of `TEMPLATE_LIST`

Comment: Apologies, I did not understand the solution fully. I did `#!/bin/bash

TEMPLATE_LIST=Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???
echo $TEMPLATE_LIST` and ran the script which didn't make sense to me at all

Comment: Do it like this: `TEMPLATE_LIST='Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???'; echo $TEMPLATE_LIST`

Comment: Now its printing `Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???` on console and not sure how will this validate any input strings.  Am using `GNU bash, version 4.3.42`. Sorry if am missing something basic here

Comment: Use it like this: `shopt -s nullglob; echo $TEMPLATE_LIST` and you will understand it better

Comment: @anubhava Actually I am receiving these 2 variables to a function . So the `echo` command don't work here as the real file is somewhere else . The function should just check if the name matches any templates then return 1 else 0 .  I tried directly printing it but not returning any output : `$ TEMPLATE_LIST="Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???"
$ echo $TEMPLATE_LIST
Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???
$ echo $TEMPLATE_LIST | grep TEST_12.csv
$`

Comment: Can you show your function code in question. Also what do you mean by `receiving these 2 variables`? You question has only single variable: `TEMPLATE_LIST` with multiple glob patterns.

Comment: code will be like `TEMPLATE_LIST="Testing_????.csv TEST_??.csv Sample.???"  ; FILE_NAME="Sample.csv" ; <<CHECK_FOR_THE_MATCH_HERE>>` . And the files are not present at the location where this script is running .

Comment: So you want to match against just one filename i.e. `FILE_NAME`?

Comment: You can try: `for f in $TEMPLATE_LIST; do [[ $FILE_NAME == $f ]] && echo "matched: $f"; done`